# get values from HorizontalPicker

Tags: android

I'm using blazSolar's HorizontalPicker from [this](https://github.com/blazsolar/HorizontalPicker), how do I get values from item/number that I picked

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your question in the current form is not a good fit. SO is for concrete questions. If you have problems getting this to work, please add your non-working code to the question and describe as precisely as possible what does not work and how it fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have checked example provided with that library, it is given clearly how to get click events in it.
This the code from example itself

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    HorizontalPicker picker = (HorizontalPicker) findViewById(R.id.picker);
    picker.setOnItemClickedListener(this);
    picker.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(int index)    {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Item selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onItemClicked(int index) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Item clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works with a little modification